# How to list all the recently installed softwares in linux other than rpm and yum command

Tags: linux, command, rpm, yum

I want to list all the recently installed softwares in linux other than rpm and yum command(because these commands will list only the softwares installed using them). I want to list apps installed from all the sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Software can be installed using so many ways that you can't think about all. Of course you can check in `/opt` and `/usr/local` but it's big probability you will miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the basic interpretation of what an "installation" is: placing an executable program anywhere under `PATH`, you can do what you want by searching recently modified files in `PATH` directories:

```
for d in ${PATH//:/ }; do
  if test -d "$d"; then
    find "$d" -type f -executable -mtime -1
  fi
done
```

This snippet takes `PATH` (which is a concatenation of directory names separated by colon), and for each directory finds executable files which were modified within last day.

To find executables installed within, e.g. 2 days, use `-mtime -2`.

Surely, this implies some level of trust that nothing malicious was done during installation because a bad player can easily adjust the modification times through, e.g. `touch` command.